# Flexbox div with column direction and inner max-width breaks in IE11

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

If I add a max-width in an inner element of a position absolute flex div it breaks in IE11. This means that it does not respect the width set for the inner element.

http://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/QGqvOx

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <span>test</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>test2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.inner {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 480px;
  max-width: 100%; // this breaks in IE11
}
```

If I change flex-direction to row it "fixes" it but it does not help in the case I'm trying to solve.

Also if I set a width in the container it also "fixes" it, but I cannot set a predifined width in my container.

Any ideas on how to make it work with flex direction column?

Comment: I think the issue with IE11 is not knowing what `100%` means in `max-width: 100%` on the flex item. That's why a defined width on the container gets it to work. Without a width on the container, IE11 resolves to `max-width: auto`, it appears.

Comment: Also, you're working in two areas known for lots of bugs: flexbox/IE11 & flexbox/flex-direction: column.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching to `max-width: 100vw;`. I know this would not work for elements that have a definied width, so my "hack" includes an escape for applying `100vw` **only** for elements that don't have an specified value.

Here is an updated codepen that works:

http://codepen.io/alansouzati/pen/NbwKqj

**CSS**

```
.inner {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 480px;
  max-width: 100vw; // this works in IE11
}
```